# wx python mysteriously adding a newline character to GUI output

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython, sizer

so the goal here is to take an input from the user and display relevant data from an excel sheet.
Our problem is a rather minor, but irritating one...
When the input doesn't get a match from the database, we will display a message saying that the input number was invalid. We used a helper function to format the output to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOmrt.jpg)

Here's the formatting code:

```
    def makeRMAString(self, RMAnum, DMRnum, serial, status, cdate, udate):
        rma_string = 'RMA#\t: {}\nDMR#\t: {} \nSerial#\t: {}\nStatus\t: {}\nCreated\t: {}\nUpdate\t: {}'
        return rma_string.format(RMAnum, DMRnum, serial, status, cdate, udate)
```

Screenshot shows that all is well when the input matches something in the database. When it doesn't, we execute the following line:

```
self.rmaData.Label = self.makeRMAString('Invalid RMA number', '' , '', '', '', '')
```

And this is where the issue occurs; instead of having a nicely formatted output, the 'Invalid RMA number' gets pushed into the next line as if there was a nextline added in:
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCkyK.jpg)

I launched from command prompt to see the output, and it looks just fine there. [Here's proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3PGU.jpg)

We are using wxpython's BoxSizer to help:

```
self.rmaData = wx.StaticText(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, self.makeRMAString('','','','','',''))
self.sizer_rmaHoriz = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
self.sizer_rmaHoriz.Add(self.rmaData, 4, wx.ALIGN_LEFT|wx.CENTER, 15)
self.rmaData.SetFont(font)
```

We are using python 2.7.10

Comment: I think it's just wrapping the long string as the width of your window/control is too narrow. Try increasing the width of your window/control.

Comment: When you add `self.rmaData` to the sizer you are specifying a `proportion` of `4`. I suspect that is wrong, use `0` or `1`, unless you specifically want a proportion of 4

Comment: @JustinEzequiel, thanks for helping. That didn't seem to be the issue because I tried to fill in all the  fields with "Invalid RMA number" and they all display just fine in the given space of the window. The wrapping happens only when I have just one field with "Invalid RMA number" and empty strings in the others.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony, thanks for the suggestion. That change led to a horizontally squished layout. Seems like the '4' specification is there to reserve a panel large enough to house the texts that will be displayed.

Comment: Your use of a formatted string being thrust as the single entry into a horizontal boxsizer with a proportion of 4, really is a hack. You are relying on a hardcoded formatted string. In reality, you should endevour to put the individual items into a grid sizer of some sort. I still think that your issue revolves around this misuse of the sizer

Comment: @RolfofSaxony yeah I definitely think it's a sizer related issue. I will look into utilizing "a grid sizer of some sort", do you have any recommended resources for an in-depth look at the sizers?

Comment: @RolfofSaxony Wow, I was only expecting a link to some detailed info on GridBagSizer, not a demo! Thank you so much! This fixed the formatting issue! You're a gem in the human condition! Rock on!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested a demo of a Grid sizer.
I've chosen a `GridBagSizer`, it seems the most appropriate to your requirement.

```
import wx  
data = [
        ["99550","539761","016833-0695","Shipped","03/27/20","Unknown"],
        ["99551","539761","xxxxxx-xxxx","Shipped","03/22/20","Unknown"],
        ["99554","539761","016833-0695","Warehouse 1","01/12/19","Unknown"],
        ['Invalid RMA number','','','','','',''],
        ["99555","539761","777777-0695","Warehouse 2","02/27/20","Unknown"],
        ["99556","539761","016833-XXXX","Shipped","03/27/20","03/24/20"],
        ['Invalid RMA number','','','','','','']
        ]
        
class Example(wx.Frame): 
   
    def __init__(self, parent, title): 
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent, title = title) 
             
        self.InitUI() 
        self.Centre() 
        self.Show()      
         
    def InitUI(self): 
        self.idx = 0       
        panel = wx.Panel(self) 
        sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(0,0)

        self.rma = wx.TextCtrl(panel,style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER) 
        sizer.Add(self.rma, pos = (0, 1), flag = wx.ALIGN_CENTRE_VERTICAL)  
        EnterB = wx.Button(panel, label = "Enter RMA") 
        sizer.Add(EnterB, pos = (0,2),flag = wx.ALL, border = 5)    
        
        text = wx.StaticText(panel, label = "RMA   :") 
        sizer.Add(text, pos = (1, 0), flag = wx.ALIGN_CENTRE_VERTICAL|wx.ALL, border = 5)
            
        self.tc = wx.TextCtrl(panel, style=wx.TE_READONLY, size=(150,-1)) 
        sizer.Add(self.tc, pos = (1, 1), flag = wx.EXPAND) 
             
        text1 = wx.StaticText(panel, label = "DMR   :") 
        sizer.Add(text1, pos = (2, 0), flag = wx.ALIGN_CENTRE_VERTICAL|wx.ALL, border = 5) 
        
        self.tc1 = wx.TextCtrl(panel, style=wx.TE_READONLY) 
        sizer.Add(self.tc1, pos = (2,1), flag = wx.EXPAND) 
             
        text2 = wx.StaticText(panel,label = "Serial :") 
        sizer.Add(text2, pos = (3, 0), flag = wx.ALIGN_CENTRE_VERTICAL|wx.ALL, border = 5) 
            
        self.tc2 = wx.TextCtrl(panel, style=wx.TE_READONLY) 
        sizer.Add(self.tc2, pos = (3,1), flag = wx.EXPAND) 
            
        text3 = wx.StaticText(panel,label = "Status :") 
        sizer.Add(text3, pos = (4, 0), flag = wx.ALIGN_CENTRE_VERTICAL|wx.ALL, border = 5)
            
        self.tc3 = wx.TextCtrl(panel, style=wx.TE_READONLY) 
        sizer.Add(self.tc3, pos = (4,1),flag = wx.EXPAND) 
             
        text4 = wx.StaticText(panel,label = "Created:") 
        sizer.Add(text4, pos = (5, 0), flag = wx.ALIGN_CENTRE_VERTICAL|wx.ALL, border = 5) 
            
        self.tc4 = wx.TextCtrl(panel, style=wx.TE_READONLY) 
        sizer.Add(self.tc4, pos = (5,1), flag = wx.EXPAND) 
    
        text5 = wx.StaticText(panel,label = "Update :") 
        sizer.Add(text5, pos = (6, 0), flag = wx.ALIGN_CENTRE_VERTICAL) 
            
        self.tc5 = wx.TextCtrl(panel, style=wx.TE_READONLY) 
        sizer.Add(self.tc5, pos = (6,1), flag = wx.EXPAND)          
    
        Next = wx.Button(panel, label = "Demo") 
            
        sizer.Add(Next, pos = (7, 1)) 
            
        panel.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)

        EnterB.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnRma)
        self.rma.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.OnRma)
        Next.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnNext)
        
    def OnRma(self, event):
        rma = self.rma.GetValue()
        idx = [i for i, e in enumerate(data) if e[0] == rma]
        if idx:
            self.idx = idx[0]
            self.OnNext(None)
        else:
            self.tc.SetValue('Invalid RMA number')                       
            self.tc1.SetValue('')                       
            self.tc2.SetValue('')                       
            self.tc3.SetValue('')                       
            self.tc4.SetValue('')                       
            self.tc5.SetValue('')                       

    def OnNext(self, event):
        self.rma.SetValue('')                       
        self.tc.SetValue(data[self.idx][0])                       
        self.tc1.SetValue(data[self.idx][1])                       
        self.tc2.SetValue(data[self.idx][2])                       
        self.tc3.SetValue(data[self.idx][3])                       
        self.tc4.SetValue(data[self.idx][4])                       
        self.tc5.SetValue(data[self.idx][5])                       
        self.idx += 1
        if self.idx > len(data) - 1:
            self.idx = 0
        
app = wx.App() 
Example(None, title = 'GridBag Demo') 
app.MainLoop()
```

Useage:

- input an RMA number (99550, 99551, 99554, 99555 or 99556) and press Enter or the `Enter Rma` button
- enter some invalid RMA  and press Enter or the `Enter Rma` button
- Click the `Demo` button, it will scroll through the data

[image]

[image]